# GetExtendedTcpTable (iphlpapi.dll) returns undocumented error code -1073741823

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, networking

I try to retrieve windows tcp table while tcp connections are intensively established in parallel.

In [code example](https://github.com/paatrofimov/tcp-table-error-demo/blob/master/Program.cs) one task is establishing many tcp connections and not releasing them, eventually leading to `SocketException`, and the other is reading tcp table with `iphlpapi.dll` in parallel. When `SocketException` in first task occurs, all previous connections are released and same cycle repeats.

So, on my machine tcp table is read well and no exceptions are thrown. But on other set of machines same code makes `GetExtendedTcpTable` return undocumented error code `-1073741823`, making code throw on [line 98](https://github.com/paatrofimov/tcp-table-error-demo/blob/master/Program.cs#L98).

What is this error code and why does it occur only at specific machines?

The issue is not googling well. I found only one related [issue](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1294) raised and there are no comments explaining such error code origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be [STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL](http://errorco.de/win32/ntstatus-h/status_unsuccessful/0xc0000001/) which is rather generic and these NTSTATUS codes are not really supposed to be returned by WinAPI functions like this.

I would suggest that you just retry the failing call when you get this error. Since it is a bit of a unknown, you should not retry forever, give up after x number of tries and/or seconds.

For `GetTcpTable` [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcptable):

> **STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL**:
>
> If you receive this return code then calling the function again is usually enough to clear the issue and get the desired result. This return code can be a consequence of the system being under high load. For example, if the size of the TCP connection table changes by more than 2 additional items 3 consecutive times.